# Json serialization in JavaScriptSerializer C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, serialization, jsonconvert

I have object in my app in c# i need to serialize it to JSON but I need to custom the result json to be like below :

```
My class : 
 public class OrderStatus
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public int statusNo { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
    }
```

I need  to convert it to

```
{
      "1": {
        "icon": "orange_warning",
        "title": "Pending Processing",
        "message":
          "We are processing your payment on our end which could take up to 30 minutes",
        "description":
          "Feel free to continue shopping while we process your payment. You can check the status of your order in Order History at any time."
      },
      "2": {
        "icon": "done_success",
        "title": "Order Successfully Placed",
        "message": "",
        "description":
          "We have sent an email to your email address confirming your order."
      }
}
```

the number is shown in json  is StatusNo in my class I use this method to serialize the class

```
new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(model)
```

Comment: This question was extremely low quality, Please read [ask] and in future add the appropriate information needed to answer it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to my mental powers, I would guess, that you have a *list* of `OrderStatus` and that the key in your resulting json is the `statusNo` property of your C# class.

To get a specific structure as JSON you should always create *special classes* that match the structure and convert between your classes and at the end use the default JSON serialization process. In your case it could look something like this:

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var orders = new List<OrderStatus>
        {
            new OrderStatus
            {
                title = "Pending Processing",
                statusNo = 1,
                description = "Feel free to continue shopping while we process your payment. You can check the status of your order in Order History at any time.",
                message = "We are processing your payment on our end which could take up to 30 minutes",
                icon= "orange_warning",
            },
            new OrderStatus
            {
                title = "Order Successfully Placed",
                statusNo = 2,
                description = "We have sent an email to your email address confirming your order.",
                message = "",
                icon= "done_success",
            },
        };

        var jsonStructure = orders
            .ToDictionary(order => order.statusNo, order => new OrderStatusJson { icon = order.icon, title = order.title, message = order.message, description = order.description });

        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonStructure, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });

        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class OrderStatusJson
{
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class OrderStatus
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int statusNo { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}
```

Some other related tips:

- On the C# side use PascalCase for property names. Both commonly used JSON serializers (Newtonsoft and Microsoft) can be configured to use the correct  casing for both sides.
- If need a bunch of mappings between different types you should take a look at [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org).

Answer (score 0):

the structure you want to convert from that class is not have harmony.
the good way to convert that is change your structure.
for that you can use [Json2csharp.com](https://json2csharp.com/). copy your json structure and past into that.